# Compare pandas dataframe columns to sql table dataframe columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am working on creating an application that will load up a CSV into one dataframe and a SQL lookup table in another.

The first frame has columns: col1, col2, ..., coln.

The second frame is a lookup table containing just col1 and col2.

The lookup table looks like

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| AB | 123 |
| AB | 234 |
| BC | 456 |

and so on. The first table needs to have a valid combination of keys. I want to get the record set that are invalid.

I need to do something like "if the PAIR of keys doesn't exist, then grab the record. else drop"

I think I could do a nested loop through each one, but am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, such as with `pd.merge` or something.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
... create two dataframes
...

frame = d1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True, left_on=['col1', 'col2']).loc[lambda x: x['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

The correct syntax to capture the fallout records is:

```
frame = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True, left_on=cols, right_on=cols).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
```